# How to pass information from one form to another without global variable or arguments when creating new form

Tags: c#, visual-studio

It may seem like this question has been asked a million times before, and in it's simplest variant it has.

How can we pass information from one form to another?

Yeah easy people say, and every answer I can find either involves global variables or passing the value into an argument when creating a new instance of the form I'm looking to tell the wonderful news about the new value of my variable.

Global variables may seem like a simple solution but having tried solving the problem with them, after just TWO I can easily see how this way madness and utter confusion lies.

So create a new version of the form with an argument? Yeah but I already have this form open, I don't want to have to close and open a new form every time a variable somewhere else changes.

In a sentence my question is: How do we pass values from one form to another without global variables or opening arguments?

This was marked as duplicate of an existing question but the answer linked seemed to be exactly what I was trying to avoid, opening a new instance of the form with varying arguments. Apologies if it's just me not understanding what's really going on here.

Comment: You pass a reference to the first form to the second form when you open it, then the second form has access to the public fields of the first form (and the first form has access to the public fields of the second form since it created it). Classes use public properties to expose information all the time, not sure why you say that doing this with a Form class will cause 'madness and confusion'?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that makes sense now. I mean passing information around by setting and resetting global variables is something that I can imagine losing track of very quickly.